# How can I get the CSRF Token in functional tests

Tags: playframework-2.1

How can I get the CSRF Token in functional tests? It doesn't work to save a token in the session and submit it in the URL.

```
"The `send` action" should {
  "return status code 400 if subject is invalid" in new WithApp with Context {
    val token = CSRF.Token(42.toString)
    val Some(result) = route(FakeRequest(POST, helper.CSRF(routes.ContactUs.send())(token).toString())
      .withFormUrlEncodedBody(
        ("subject" -> "invalid"),
        ("name" -> "Lucky Luke"),
        ("email" -> "test@test.com"),
        ("message" -> "test")
      )
      .withSession(TOKEN_NAME -> token.toString)
    )

    status(result) must equalTo(BAD_REQUEST)
    contentType(result) must beSome("application/json")
    charset(result) must beSome("utf-8")
}
```

**Edit**

`token.toString` doesn't return the token as string. The accessor `token.value` returns a proper token which can be send in the session. So a working example is:

```
"The `send` action" should {
  "return status code 400 if subject is invalid" in new WithApp with Context {
    val token = CSRF.Token(42.toString)
    val Some(result) = route(FakeRequest(POST, helper.CSRF(routes.ContactUs.send())(token).toString())
      .withFormUrlEncodedBody(
        ("subject" -> "invalid"),
        ("name" -> "Lucky Luke"),
        ("email" -> "test@test.com"),
        ("message" -> "test")
      )
      .withSession(TOKEN_NAME -> token.value)
    )

    status(result) must equalTo(BAD_REQUEST)
    contentType(result) must beSome("application/json")
    charset(result) must beSome("utf-8")
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your solution works but in order not to do this for every request and have cleaner tests you can make use of a custom `GlobalSettings`. This does 2 things: removes the csrf checking filter but still provides a csrf token in the session so the csrf helper does not choke.

```
object TestGlobal extends WithFilters(FakeCSRF)
object FakeCSRF extends Filter{
  def apply(next: (RequestHeader) => Result)(request: RequestHeader) = {
    next(CSRF.addRequestToken(request,CSRF.generate))
  }
}
```

Then define a custom scope for your tests:

```
trait testApp extends Scope with Around{
  def around[T](t: => T)(implicit evidence$1: AsResult[T]) = {
    Helpers.running(FakeApplication(withGlobal = Some(TestGlobal)))(AsResult(t))
  }
}
```

And now, in your tests, you can do:

```
"The `send` action" should {
  "return status code 400 if subject is invalid" in new testApp {
    val Some(result) = route(FakeRequest(POST, routes.ContactUs.send())
     .withFormUrlEncodedBody(...)
  }
}
```

Note that there's no mention of CSRF in the test code.

**Caveat**: This does not work if you don't **route** your fake request but instead call the controller directly. The TestGlobal won't be used so you need to use your, more verbose, solution.